# De Mysql a Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Necesito pasar esta consulta a laravel-
**detalle_comprobante** es mi tabla
he intentado con formas como esta

```
$detalle=DetalleComprobante::sum('medicamento_id'.'cantidad')
                           ->groupBy('medicamento_id')
                           ->orderBySum('cantidad');
```

pero literalmente nunca he pasado una consulta de mysql a laravel se hacer consultas por mysql y en laravel pero interpretarlas de una a otra se me es dificil ya que llevo poco tiempo usando las 2 cosas. 
si alguien podria ayudarme le agradesco de antemano
el fin es obtener los mas vendidos: este codigo si me funciona en mi localhost

> Consulta

```
SELECT detalle_comprobantes.medicamento_id,SUM(detalle_comprobantes.cantidad) AS totalventas
FROM detalle_comprobantes
GROUP BY detalle_comprobantes.medicamento_id
ORDER BY SUM(detalle_comprobantes.cantidad)DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: Y que has intentado?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: $detalle=DetalleComprobante::sum('medicamento_id'.'cantidad')->groupBy('medicamento_id')->orderBySum('cantidad');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pudieras intentarlo de este modo:

```
$data = DetalleComprobante::select('detalle_comprobantes.medicamento_id')
                        ->selectRaw('SUM(detalle_comprobantes.cantidad) as totalventas')
                        ->groupBy('detalle_comprobantes.medicamento_id')
                        ->orderByRaw('SUM(detalle_comprobantes.cantidad) DESC')
                        ->skip(0)
                        ->take(5)
                        ->get();
```

- Usamos `selectRaw()` para pasar por dentro una consulta SQL que sería la función de agregación `SUM`.
- Como vas a agrupar por la sumatoria de `cantidad` entonces puedes usar el método `orderByRaw()` donde igual podemos pasar una consulta SQL directa
- El hecho de `LIMIT 0 5` lo puedes obtener con el método `take()` y por dentro pasas la cantidad de registros que deseas retornar

Comment: Vaya funciona a la perfección, pero aun tengo dudas, osea utilizo el SelectRaw y orderbyraw para incluir los sum, y el from detalle_comprobante porque ya no va??

Comment: @SmithShenZySalazarYactayo por que tu modelo es la representación de tus datos/tabla con lo cual por eso ya no es necesario

Comment: Gracias.muchas gracias. Esta consulta con tu ayuda es el éxito.